# Installed packages & /home/* files sometimes reset on ddev restart (or ddev stop, start)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ddev

I've been using DDEV for a few days and it's great.

However I have found if I run `ddev ssh` to ssh into the container, and install packages via `npm / aptitude` etc, or if I create new files in the `~/` home directory, *sometimes* those packages / files get removed / reset when I `ddev stop > ddev start` or `ddev restart`

It doesn't happen *all* the time, just sometimes. I've restarted it a bunch of times, and I can't work out any pattern as to when the packages/files get wiped, and when they don't.

I've trawled through the config files, and the documentation, and the github issue queue, but I can't find anything about it. I am running the `ddev` on a Mac, installed with Homebrew. I have the latest version of Docker and Docker Compose.

My question is: How can I make it so my installed packages / files will persist when I restart `ddev`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just `ddev ssh` and install, everything is thrown away when the container is recreated or rm'd.

Edit: As of ddev v1.8.0, you can just use `webimage_additional_packages: [php7.1-ldap]`, see [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-debian-packages-with-webimage_extra_packages-and-dbimage_extra_packages)

Original approach:

Try this post-start hook example from the [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extending-commands/#adding-additional-php-modules-example). This general approach should work well.

```
hooks:
    post-start:
      # Install php modules and then tell php-fpm to reload
      - exec: "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-ldap php7.1-tidy && killall -HUP php-fpm"
```